# Using CartThrob and Worldpay pre-authorization?

Tags: ee2, cartthrob, ecommerce, payment-gateway, worldpay

I want to essentially defer a payment with Worldpay, apparently this is possible using something called 'authorization'/'pre-authorization' which is detailed in their documentation:

https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/authorize-payment

We're using EE2 and Carthrob 2.x with a Worldpay integration, and I'm trying to figure out if this is possible. I can't seem to find any documentation on this, and going through the code is proving a bit frustrating.

Does anyone know if this is possible using CartThrob and the default Worldpay integration? Or would this require modification to the payment Gateay?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm with Vector; we make CartThrob)

There are two scenarios:

- You do the authorization with CartThrob, but do the capture later in the Worldpay admin interface. This would require a change to the payment gateway but it's very quick; it would just need the addition of a line or two to the plugin.
- You do the authorization with CartThrob but then also want to do the capture inside CartThrob. This would take more work because that new and separate capture function would need to be made along with an interface for it.

Also I assume you're using the Worldpay redirect gateway, not an on-site Worldpay gateway. If so, please note that that uses a different API than the one you linked to. It uses http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/htmlredirect/htmlredirect.htm#Common/TitlePage.htm.

Feel free to contact us at support@cartthrob.com if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks Matt, your response is much appreciated! I will go through in detail what you have said soon, but I have one question: I thought that CartThrob only offered paid support? Could I contact support@ with a query like this and no support contract? Cheers

Comment: @SeanDunwoody in most cases, you're welcome to contact us and we can either point you to a solution, or offer a support contract for us to do the work for you.